# How to parse malformed RSS feed from third party sites using php?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, rss

I'm trying to parse RSS feeds from some medias. My script works for most of them. The problem is that I need to agregate all of them, eventhough they are malformed.

I don't manage to get the description of these two feeds. How could I proceed anyway ?

Here is my script :

```php
<?php
function RSS_items ($url) {
    $i = 0;
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load($url);
    $channels = $doc->getElementsByTagName('channel');
    foreach($channels as $channel) {
        $items = $channel->getElementsByTagName('item');
        foreach($items as $item) {
            $i++;
            $y[$i]['title'] = $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->firstChild->textContent;
            $y[$i]['link'] = $item->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->firstChild->textContent;
            $y[$i]['updated'] = $item->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->firstChild->textContent;
            $y[$i]['description'] = $item->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->firstChild->textContent;
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r ($y);
    echo '</pre>';
}
// the two malformed feeds
RSS_items ('http://www.lefigaro.fr/rss/figaro_actualites-a-la-une.xml');
RSS_items ('https://francais.rt.com/rss');
?>
```

Comment: The code doesn't work for which one? Does return any error?

Comment: It doesn't work for both of them. No error. It doesn't parse the description.

Comment: Maybe problem is in using `firstChild`. Because selected tag hasn't any child that you want to select first of them. When i removed it, code worked.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Is it because of the line breaks at the beginning of each description ? I'm just wondering why the original script (which is not mine) was coded with `firstchild`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem of your code is in useing [`firstChild`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.firstchild) property that select first child of element. But in target XML, `description` tag hasn't any childs that you want to select first of them. Remove it from code. The result should be like this

```
$item->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->textContent;
```

Comment: So I should remove `firstchild` only for the `description` tag ? As I told you above, I was wondering why the original script (which is not mine) was coded with `firstchild`.  Is `description` the only tag without `firstchild` ?

Comment: @Guillaume As i said in answer `firstChild` select child of element. If another tag hasn't child, you can remove it.

Comment: I know what is `firstchild` considering CSS. But I'm not confortable in the XML context. 
I found this : "Element nodes has a nodeType of 1, so if the first child node is not an element node, it moves to the next node, and checks if this node is an element node. This continues until the first child node (which must be an element node) is found. This way, the result will be correct in all browsers."
So, it seems that if I want to get my script working with ALL the feeds, I need to check the type of the firstchild and then take into account if it's a text object or a CDATAsection. Am I right ?

Comment: @Guillaume Yes, but you should do this work when your tag has multiple child. For example if `description` tag has multiple child, you should iterate through child and check if type of child is text or CDATA.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native tongue and I have some difficulties to explain the point I don't get. In the context of an XML `description` tag, what is a `firstchild` ? Could you show me a `description` tag with a `firstchild` and a `description` tag with several childs, please ?

Comment: OK, so a description tag with multiple <p> or <li> (for example) in it has still one child. Is that right ?
If it's right, so I've never seen an XML feed with multiple child (eventhough my parser is running with hundreds of them). That's why I was asking.

Comment: @Guillaume No, it isn't right unless that `p` or `li` writed as text. https://jsfiddle.net/jawykjfr/1/